# GCP MySQL query logging

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have a managed MySQL instance on GCP. Where would I find a query log? Is this something I need to enable first somewhere? I have read their documentation ( https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/how-to ) and didn't find it helpful on this topic.

Comment: I've not used MySQL on GCP, but if you can run the mysql client (which you have to be able to do - no?) run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE %log%` or similar and that should point you to any logs you have that are operational. p.s. welcome to the forum!:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags) and [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags#tips-general-log).

Relevant part:

> To make your general or slow query logs available, enable the
>   corresponding flag and set the log_output flag to FILE. This makes the
>   log output available using the [Logs Viewer](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) in the Google Cloud
>   Platform Console. Note that Stackdriver logging charges apply.
>
> If log_output is set to NONE, you will not be able to access the logs.
>   If you set log_output to TABLE, the log output is placed in a table in
>   your database. If this table becomes large, it can affect instance
>   restart time or cause the instance to lose its SLA coverage; for this
>   reason, the TABLE option is not recommended. If needed, you can
>   truncate your log tables by using the API. For more information, see
>   the instances.truncateLog reference page.

Comment: Thank you - ours is set to FILE, working on getting permissions to view logs in Stackdriver now!

Comment: After setting this up, I am only able to view error and activity logs - not query logs. Any more tips?

Comment: Is `slow_query_log` set to `on` ?

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in ALL queries, not just the slow ones... the slow queries portion is working OK.

Comment: Is `general_log` set?

Comment: It is now - and everything is great. Thank you very much Phil!

Comment: When I view the logs all the queries are broken up.  SELECT will be in one line and then further down the log will have FROM on its own line.  The log software doesn't break up the query properly.  This isn't usable.